# Перенос текста из формы на другую страницу

Tags: php, http, get

Как перенести текст из формы на 1-ой странице на другую страницу, но именно через метод get?

Comment: Через get передавать текст с формы? о_О Что за извращение?)

Comment: Не нравиться не передавай!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input value="<?php echo $_GET[number] ?>">
```

Comment: И значение параметра number из GET будет в окошке инпута.

Answer (score 4):

Там где форма атрибут метод поставь как get А поле называется number. А на страничке

```
<?php
$number=$_GET['number'];
echo "$number";
?>
Если я не ошибаюсь то так. Вообще гет и пост сильно не отличаются.
```

Comment: Нужно чтобы на другой странице переходил в форму

Comment: Только лучше просто

    echo $number;

Кавычки ни к чему.